# Mediation analysis (lavaan in R vs. Hayes MACRO SPSS)

Tags: mediation, lavaan

I have a really basic question when conducting mediation analysis.
When reading articles, some scholars use lavaan package in R and other use Hayes MACRO.
Are there any differences? For example, if I wanna perform simple X->Y->Z mediation, which software should I use?
I am not sure here is the right place to ask, but hope somebody has an answer.

Comment: One advantage of using programs for structural equation modeling (SEM) such as lavaan for analyzing mediation models is that SEM programs can handle overidentified models (e.g., path models in which some direct effects are constrained to zero). Overidentified models can be tested via a chi-square test of model fit . Also, SEM programs are more flexible in that they offer a wider range of estimation methods (e.g., robust maximum likelihood, bias-corrected bootstrap), including methods for handling missing data such as full information maximum likelihood.